# Implementing a modified do-while loop in Python i.e. do at least once and another time at the end of the loop?

Tags: python, loops, selenium, for-loop, while-loop

I am having problems implementing something that equates a do while loop.

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

I am scraping a site and the results pages are paginated, i.e.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... NEXT
```

I am iterating through the pages using a test condition for the existence of the `NEXT` link. If there is one results page, There is no `NEXT` link so I will just scrape that first page. If there is more than one page, the last page also has no `NEXT` link. So the scraper function would also work on that page. The scraping function is called `findRecords()`

So I am isolating my `NEXT` link using:

```
next_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']")
```

So I want to run a loop that performs the scrape at least once (when there is one or more results page). I am also clicking the `NEXT` button using a click() function. The code I have so far is:

```
while True:
    findRecords()
    next_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']")
    if not next_link:
        break
    next_link.click()
```

This is not working. Well, it works and it scrapes but when it reaches the last page it give me a `NoSuchElementException` as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "try.py", line 47, in 
>           next_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']")
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
>           'value': value})['value']
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']"}
>         (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.89)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64)

I know it's true that the element does not exist on that last page, because like i said before, the `NEXT` element does not exist on the last page.

So how do i fix my while loop to be able to scrape a single page result and/or that last page when the condition is not true and also elegantly break out of the while loop without giving me that hideous error?

PS: Other than the while loop above, I have also tried the following:

```
is_continue = True
while is_continue:
    findRecords()
    next_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']")
    if next_link:
        is_continue = True
        next_link.click()
    else:
        is_continue = False
```

And if it is any help, here is my scraper function `findRecords()` as well:

```
def findRecords():
    filename = "sam_" + letter + ".csv"
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    tableList = bsObj.find_all("table", {"class":"width100 menu_header_top_emr"}) 
    tdList = bsObj.find_all("td", {"class":"menu_header width100"})

    for table,td in zip(tableList,tdList):
            a = table.find_all("span", {"class":"results_body_text"})
            b = td.find_all("span", {"class":"results_body_text"})
            with open(filename, "a") as csv_file:
                csv_file.write(', '.join(tag.get_text().strip() for tag in a+b) +'\n')
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, and show us the complete stack trace.

Comment: @user2357112 I have fixed both to match what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `find_elements`, it would return either list of WebElement or empty list. So just check its length as below :-

```
while True:
    findRecords()
    next_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']")
    if len(next_link) == 0:
        break
    next_link[0].click()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are searching for next link change code to find_elements which will return a list of size 1 if Next is present else list of size 0 but no exception.

```
next_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')][@style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;']")
```

You need to put in place logic to access the Next webelement from this list now.